# Keeping the selected value from a dropdown menu by reading it from a text file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the following code that allows the user to put the Timing Status on either On or Off

```
<html>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) 
{
    $TimingStat=$_POST['timestat'];
    $fileName = 'test.txt';

    $lines = file($fileName);
    $lines[0]="Timing_status= ". $TimingStat;

    file_put_contents($fileName, implode($lines));
    fclose( $fileName);

}
else
{
    $TimingStat=explode(" ",$lines[0]);
    $TimingStat=$TimingStat[1];
}
?>

  <form action="test.php" name="Calculation" method="post">  

    Timing Status: &nbsp;<select selected="selected" name="timestat"   VALUE="<?PHP print $TimingStat ; ?>">

<?php $attr= 'selected="selected"'; ?>

 <option VALUE="On"  <?php echo  $TimingStat == 'On' ? $attr : ''; ?>>On</option>

 <option VALUE="Off"  <?php echo  $TimingStat== 'Off' ? $attr : ''; ?>>Off</option>

</select>

<Input Type = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" Value = "Save Parameters">
 </form>

 </html>
```

It is important for me that the values be written in a text file and then the code reads from a text file.

Everything works fine, except when I refresh my page the selected value will always go to On although Off has been pressed. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You are reading your file in the if-block of your code. So when there is no submit action, no file is loaded, and therefore `$lines` does not exist. Therefore your option is not selected. You should get NOTICEs from PHP about this, if you have the proper error reporting enabled.

Comment: So once the value is submitted the code should be able to read from the text file

Comment: Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/test.php on line 33 is the error I am getting in log

Comment: Undefined variable: lines in /var/www/test.php on line 30 is another error

Comment: Yes. You have an else. Which means that the part under `if` is not executed when the part under `else` is executed. The notice you are getting also tells you that: undefined variable `lines`, like I said. PHP doesn't know that variable because it is not defined in the `else`..

Comment: If you copy your `$lines = file(....)` line to the `else` part of your code, it should work. After you've done that, try reading some tutorials about PHP syntax and design patterns (since it is generally not a good idea to copy code, don't repeat yourself)